# How can we show that one model might have higher accuracy than another model but at the same time lower AUC?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, accuracy

Assume that we have two classiﬁcation models M1 and M2 that are evaluated on ﬁve test instances. How to show with an example that M1 can have a higher accuracy than M2, while at the same time M2 has a higher area under the ROC curve (AUC) than M1?

Answer (score 1):

Normally this can happen when there's imbalance in your classes. Imagine that you want to predict these 5 values:

```
y_test = [1,0,0,0,0]
```

and your models M1 and M2 predict the following:

```
M1_pred = [0,0,0,0,0] 
M2_pred = [1,0,0,1,1]
```

Clearly we can see that M1 is biased towards class 0, getting 4/5 results correct (80% accuracy!). While the second one, only gets 3/5 values right (60% accuracy).

However, because AUC ROC is defined by both true positive rate against the false positive, combining those the M2 classifier gets a 75% auc, while M1 only a 50% because it has failed the only one positive, thus penalising the final score.

Try running this toy example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_test = [1,0,0,0,0] #ground truth

M1_pred = [0,0,0,0,0] #predictions M1
M2_pred = [1,0,0,1,1] #predictions M2

#Calculate both accuracy scores
M1_acc = accuracy_score(y_test, M1_pred) 
M2_acc = accuracy_score(y_test, M2_pred) 

#Calculate both ROC AUC
fpr1, tpr1, _ = roc_curve(y_test, M1_pred)
roc_auc1 = auc(fpr1, tpr1)
fpr2, tpr2, _ = roc_curve(y_test, M2_pred)
roc_auc2 = auc(fpr2, tpr2)

#Plot both graphs
plt.figure(figsize = (12,6))

#Graph M1
plt.subplot(121)
lw = 2
plt.plot(fpr1, tpr1, color='darkorange',
         lw=lw, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)\n ACC Score = %0.2f' % (roc_auc1, M1_acc))
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=lw, linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic ROC')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")

#Graph M2
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(fpr2, tpr2, color='darkorange',
         lw=lw, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)\n ACC Score = %0.2f' % (roc_auc2, M2_acc))
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=lw, linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic ROC')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")

plt.show()
```

and you will get something like this:

[image]